# Mouse color in graphic mode

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm working on my finale project in school and in my program the mouse is red (Graphic mode). Is there a way to change it to regular?
I heard it was easy but I couldn't find it.

thanks!

Comment: yeah, i think thats what u say. and by regular i mean the white mouse..

Comment: Try this (I can't test it in my computer) :   `mov  ax, 0ah`
  `mov  cx, 00ffh`
  `mov  dx, 8f00h`
  `mov  bx, 0`
  `int  33h` . This is suppose to change cursor to any color, if this works, we will use white color in DX.

Comment: Previous comment is for text mode, for graphics mode use this : http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_33-9.html

Comment: thanks a lot, if u can give me an example in code it will be great ! :)

Comment: Ido, I made my code run on Windows XP and works great. Take a look at it again and test it! Then you can upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: omg thanks so much,it works, and the shape is graet and even good for my project (the hand). problem solved.. and im sorry i wasnt active

Comment: oops- edit- i tried to mixed it in my project and the mouse now is like a big square in the proj and not a mouse. maybe i did something wrong :O

Comment: sorry that i asked a lot xD

Comment: ohhhhhh.. i fixed the square but now its red again (the hand)

Comment: no (sorry) the cursor is in shape of hand like in the code but the color is red still.

Comment: i know .. its white.. but when i placed it in my pruject its red again. i thought its because of the chenging palltte cause it changed when i print bmp picture but then i tried to set paltte after printing and the same...

Comment: Red is a nice color. Now, would you like to accept my answer clicking on the checkmark? I think it's been very helpful :)

Comment: ho yeah, sorry,thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my code to change the cursor shape :

```
;FROM http://lateblt.tripod.com/asm.htm
.stack 100h
.data

my_cursor DB 11111111B, 11111001B
          DB 11111111B, 11110000B
          DB 11111111B, 11110000B
          DB 11111111B, 11110000B
          DB 11111111B, 11110000B
          DB 11111111B, 11110000B
          DB 00000111B, 11000000B
          DB 00000011B, 10000000B
          DB 00000011B, 10000000B
          DB 00000111B, 11000000B
          DB 00000111B, 11000000B
          DB 00001111B, 11100000B
          DB 00011111B, 11110000B
          DB 00011111B, 11111000B
          DB 00011111B, 11111000B
          DB 00011111B, 11111000B

          DB 00000000B, 00000110B
          DB 00000000B, 00001111B
          DB 00000000B, 00001111B
          DB 00000000B, 00001111B
          DB 00000000B, 00001111B
          DB 00000000B, 00001111B
          DB 11111000B, 00111111B
          DB 11111100B, 01111111B
          DB 11111100B, 01111111B
          DB 11111000B, 00111111B
          DB 11111000B, 00111111B
          DB 11110000B, 00011111B
          DB 11100000B, 00001111B
          DB 11100000B, 00000111B
          DB 11100000B, 00000111B
          DB 11100000B, 00000111B          

.code

mov ax, @data       ;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax          ;NECESSARY TO CHANGE CURSOR COLOR.

mov ah, 0
mov al, 13h         ;MODE 320x200.
int 10h             ;START GRAPHICS MODE.

mov ax, 1           ;TURN MOUSE
int 33h             ;CURSOR ON.

mov ax, 09h
mov bx, 0ah 
mov cx, 0
mov dx, offset my_cursor ;SHAPE OF A HAND.
int 33h            ;SET MOUSE CURSOR LOOK.

repeat:            ;REPEAT UNTIL USER PRESS ANY KEY.
mov ah, 0bh
int 21h
cmp al, 0
je  repeat

mov ax, 4c00h       ;TERMINATE PROGRAM.
int 21h
```

Tested on Windows XP and TASM :

```
tasm /zi filename
tlink /v filename
filename
```

It runs great, the cursor has the shape of a hand.

Comment: I think an explanation of the cursor mask and screen mask would be useful. This is more or less a code dump of someone else's code (maybe yours?). You did attribute it to the website which is good.

Comment: Beyond my previous comment you should put `.model small` at the top, an `end` directive at the bottom, and you'll probably want to turn the cursor on with `MOV AX,01h`  `INT 33h`